# Using ApplicationSignInManager in WEB API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to log in via Web API 2. What I have done is copy some code over from the AccountController from MVC 5.2, but when I run this code, the ApplicationSignInManager is `null` and it throws an Exception.

I can't find any example projects on Github or ASP.NET.

This is my custom UserController Web API.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{

    ... // Truncated for brevity

    [Route("login")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
        var signinManager = Request.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();

        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        SignInStatus result = 
            signinManager.PasswordSignIn(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);
        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            default:
               return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: manager
  Source=MicrosoftSystem.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code.AspNet.Identity.Owin
  ParamName=manager
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManagerExtensions.PasswordSignIn[TUser,TKey](SignInManager`2 manager, String userName, String password, Boolean isPersistent, Boolean shouldLockout)

Comment: @NaNerd - Did you manage to solve this? I'm stuck with the same problem

Comment: Im having the same problem as well :-(

Comment: The solution was to use OWIN. Use this tutorial to st it up -> http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/